# how to get a function return multiple plots as output

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

So I am performing a time series forecasting using XGBoost. I am using cross validation using TimeSeriesSplit. I am splitting my data into 6 folds.

The requirement is I need to write a function that can output 6 plots, one for each fold.

Sample Data:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({'date' : pd.date_range(start = '2022-01-01', end = '2023-06-30'),
                 'actual' : np.random.randint(0, 10, size = 546),
                 'predicted' : np.random.randint(0, 14, size = 546)})
df.set_index('date', inplace = True)
```

I can generate the Actual vs Predicted plot for 1 fold using:

```
ax = df.loc[(df.index > '2022-05-31') & (df.index < '2022-07-1')]['actual'].plot(figsize = (15, 5), title = 'Actual vs Pred')
df.loc[(df.index > '2022-05-31') & (df.index < '2022-07-1')]['predicted'].plot(style = '.')
plt.legend(['Actual', 'Predicted'])
plt.show()
```

or for two date ranges as below:

```
bool1 = (df.index > '2022-05-31') & (df.index < '2022-07-1')
bool2 = (df.index > '2022-10-31') & (df.index < '2022-12-1')

ax = df.loc[bool1]['actual'].plot(figsize = (15, 5), title = 'Actual vs Pred')
df.loc[bool1]['predicted'].plot(style = '.')
plt.legend(['Actual', 'Predicted'])
plt.show()

ax = df.loc[bool2]['actual'].plot(figsize = (15, 5), title = 'Actual vs Pred')
df.loc[bool2]['predicted'].plot(style = '.')
plt.legend(['Actual', 'Predicted'])
plt.show()
```

But I need to write a function that can output 6 such plots through a for loop because every time the function has to calculate the `predicted` column using `XGBoost` on the particular cross validation fold split by the `TimeSeriesSplit`.

Comment: I think you might be looking for subplots

Comment: What do you mean by "output 6 such plots"? Should these plots be created and rendered, or do you just need a handle to these plots, e.g. for saving them?

Comment: @RaJa, the function should return 6 plots, which I need to be able to view them. for ex: `plot1, plot2, plot3, plot4, plot5, plot6 = get_plots(id = 123)`

Answer (score 2):

Create your plots by calling `plt.subplots`. This provides you with the axes-object to draw you line plot and a respective handle `fig` to you plot window. You don't have to call `plt.show()` anymore.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax = df.loc[(df.index > '2022-05-31') & (df.index < '2022-07-1')['actual'].plot(figsize = (15, 5), title = 'Actual vs Pred')
df.loc[(df.index > '2022-05-31') & (df.index < '2022-07-1')]['predicted'].plot(style = '.')
ax.legend(['Actual', 'Predicted'])
```

Put this into your function and let it return the 6 `fig`-objects.

Comment: So the function should `return fig` ? No need to create an empty list and append the list during every `for` loop run for 6 folds?

Comment: Whether or not you need to call `plt.show()` depends on the environment where you run Python.  In an interactive environment, if you run the above code 6 times, 6 windows will be created and shown.  In stand-alone code, these windows will be created, but only be shown when you call `plt.show()` (or `fig.show()`). Note that `fig` and `ax` don't "contain" the plots, instead they are variables that reference the plot. You also can create multiple subplots at once, e.g. with `fig, ((ax1, ax2, ax3), (ax4, ax5, ax6)) = plt.subplots(ncols=3, nrows=2)`.

Comment: @JohanC, sorry if my query is very trivial, am new to matplotlib. I need to know how do I return the 6 plots as output of the function when the function is executed.

Comment: Well, you could make a list of each of the figures (`fig` in this code) and return that list.  But that list wouldn't be the plots themselves, it would be references to these plots.  Your question could be clearer if you'd explain what you want to do afterwards with these plots.

Comment: @JohanC, I would like to view the plots later. For ex. if a function were to return a `dataframe`, we store it in a variable and then we can later view and use it. Similary, I should be able to view the 6 plots returned by this function

Comment: @JohanC, basically requirement is the end user would enter a customer id as input to the function and should be able to see the actual vs predicted plots.

Comment: When the user enters a customer id, you can call your function with the user id as parameter, and the plot will be shown.  There is no need to create the plot beforehand.

Comment: @JohanC, interesting, thanks will code accordingly